# Looking for solution to insert PHP array to SQL database by using PDO

Tags: php, sql, arrays, loops, pdo

This is my array of order detail, array structure will be: "ids" => "qtys":

```
    $orderData = array();
    $transactionID = 1;

    $orderItems = $_POST['orders'];

        //echo json_encode($orderItems);

    foreach ($orderItems as $order){
            $qtys = $order['qty']; //Which will be "quantity" insert into database;
            $ids =  $order['id']; //Which will be "itemID" insert into database;
            $orderData["$ids"]=$qtys;
        }
```

Now I am looking for solutions to push the array inside the database:

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO item_transaction (transactionID,itemID,quantity) VALUES ($transactionID,?,?)" ;
```

How should I continue?

Comment: You should use [prepared stetement](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#multiexec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bindParam to insert it inside the loop.

something like...

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO item_transaction transactionID,itemID,quantity) VALUES (:transactionId,:itemId,:qty)");

$stmt->bindParam(':transactionId', $transactionID );
$stmt->bindParam(':itemId', $itemID);
$stmt->bindParam(':qty', $quantity);

foreach ($orderItems as $order){
     $quantity = $order['qty'];
     $itemID =  $order['id']; 
     $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Idk what this was downvoted it seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @bassxzero you need more experience then, to be able to tell PDO from mysqli. and even mysqli from mysqli that wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: Oh im sorry, that was mysqli version I will edit then

Comment: This code will result to error. You use the variables that is not declared yet.  `$quantity`,`$itemID`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you did not provide your DDL and you did not show where some of your data comes from ($transactionID ?).

```
<?php
class Handler {
    public $dbHostname      = 'DATABASE-HOSTNAME-OR-IPADDRESS-GOES-HERE';
    public $dbDatabaseName  = 'MYSQL-DBNAME-GOES-HERE';
    public $user            = 'DATABASE_USERNAME';
    public $password        = 'DATABASE_PASSWORD';
    //public $port = 3307;
    public $message;

    public function handleRequest($arg) {
        $orderItems = $arg['orders'];

        try  {
            $portChunk = ( isset($this->port) ) ? ';port=' . $this->port : null;
            $dsn = "mysql:dbname={$this->dbDatabaseName};host={$this->dbHostname}{$portChunk}";
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->password);

            $transactionID = 1;

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO item_transaction transactionID, itemID, quantity) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
            foreach ($orderItems as $order){
                $stmt->execute([$transactionID, $order['id'], $order['qty']]);
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->log('Failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
// Change the following to false to test from the web.
$commandLine = true;
$handler = new Handler();
if ( $commandLine ) {
    // run from command line
    $handler->handleRequest(['orders' => 
        ['qty' => 9,  'id' => 111],
        ['qty' => 4,  'id' => 222],
        ['qty' => 11, 'id' => 333],
    ]);
}
else {
    $handler->handleRequest($_POST);
}
```

Bear in mind that I have NOT tested this code at all. Run it and see what happens.

Comment: You may find this reading useful, [Your first db wrapper childhood deceases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)